# Close Ajax:PopupControlExtender on escape key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, popup, ajaxcontroltoolkit

How to close Ajax:PopupControlExtender on escape key press with javascript or Jquery?
Below is my html mark up for the same.

```
<td>
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtTechnologyCombo" runat="server" Width="105" ReadOnly="true" TabIndex="7">
     </asp:TextBox>
     <Ajax:PopupControlExtender ID="pceTechnology" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtTechnologyCombo"
           PopupControlID="pnlTechnology" Position="Bottom">
      </Ajax:PopupControlExtender>
      <input type="hidden" name="hidTechnologyVal" id="hidTechnologyVal" runat="server" />
      <asp:Panel ID="pnlTechnology" runat="server" Style="max-height: 150px; min-width: 160px;
           overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; padding-right: 20px;" BackColor="#f9faf6"
           BorderColor="Gray" BorderWidth="1">
           &nbsp;<asp:CheckBox ID="chkTechnologyAll" runat="server" Text="All" CssClass="chklist" />
           <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkTechnologyList" CssClass="chklist" runat="server">
           </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlTechnology" Style="width: 110px;" Visible="false">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</td>
```

I need single function which can be used to close all PopupControlExtender because I am having more than 10 such blocks.

Comment: Here is a similar post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882738/close-the-ajax-modal-popup-window-on-esc-keypress

Answer (score 1):

try following code:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) 
  { 
     $("#pceTechnology").hide();
  }   // esc
});
```